# Can I integrate a SAML application with Azure AD B2C?

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

Our current application is authenticating users with a SAML IdP. We wish to retain their implementation of SAML and update the application’s configuration with Azure AD B2C, not switch to OAuth2 or OpenID Connect. Does Azure AD B2C currently support receiving authentication requests via SAML? I am unable to find this in the documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Azure AD B2C does not support integrating with applications / relaying parties via SAML yet.**

You can support this ask and keep up to date on its progress by voting for it in the Azure AD B2C feedback forum: [(Application) SAML Protocol support](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/15334323-saml-protocol-support).

Comment: This answer is now out of date. B2C does support SAML. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/saml-technical-profile

Comment: @HockeyJ  That link is for connecting B2C to a SAML identity provider, not for using SAML with a relying party.  The other answers below about SAML support being in preview (for a relyng party) still apply.    See also [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/relyingparty) , which says "The SAML2 represents the SAML 2.0 protocol standard as per OASIS specification. Do not use a SAML token in production".

Answer (score 5):

Azure B2C does (has for a while) provide SAML connectivity through custom policies in the Identity Experience Framework currently in public preview - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-overview-custom

Answer (score 0):

You can configure Configure SAML Relying party application:

- https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/saml-sp

The full documentation can be found here:

- https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/saml-sp/blob/master/saml-rp-spec.md

**NOTE: AS Per July 2019, SAML Relying Party support is available as a preview feature**